# Can't get 'modifier_apply()' to actually apply the modification

Tags: python, boolean-modifier

I'm looping through the .stl files of a folder to perform a boolean modification on them. Once the boolean modification is performed, I want to delete the boolean operand object (`modif_obj`) to save the modified .stl alone, and then go to the next .stl file.
The code below shows the part where I'm performing the boolean modification itself.
The problem that I have is that when I delete `modifier_obj`, the boolean modification also disappears, and the original .stl file doesn't show any modification.

```
        print(f"APPLYING BOOL MODIF {index}!!")
        bool_mod = tile_obj.modifiers.new("Boolean", "BOOLEAN")
        bool_mod.operation = 'DIFFERENCE'
        bool_mod.object = modifier_obj
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=bool_mod.name)
        bpy.data.objects.remove(modifier_obj, do_unlink=True)
        print(f"MODIFICATION FINISHED!!\n")
```

PS: I checked what happens when I comment the line `bpy.data.objects.remove(modifier_obj, do_unlink=True)` and I observe that the boolean modification was correctly performed but it was **not applied**, so when I remove `modifier_obj`, the boolean modification also disappears.

Any idea of what's going on here?

Thanks!! :)

Comment: This is a curve. I don't think you can define a boolean modifier on a curve, even if bpy seems to allow it.

Comment: No, it's not a curve. The model I'm performing the boolean modification to (tile_obj) is a tile-shaped model. Also as I said, the boolean modification actually works, it just only disappears when I delete the boolean operand. Therefore it means that the modification was done but not applied.

Comment: ok, What are these objects? If I try it with two cubes, that seems to work fine.

Comment: The objects are two .stl meshes: the mesh to modify is a tile (like very flat cube) and the boolean operand is also like a cube. The goal is to make a cavity at the base of the tile.
If I check what the script did after `modifier_apply()`, I see that the modification was correctly performed. The problem comes when deleting `modifier_obj` as it also deletes the boolean modification.
When doing boolean modifications manually, you first make the boolean modification and then you have to *apply* it if you want it to remain on the model.

Comment: is the boolean modifier working well when applied manually ?

Comment: if yes, you can try to get the evaluated object instead of applying the modifier.

Comment: yes it is working well when applied manually

Comment: In my case, I see that `modifier_apply()' performs the modification but it doesn't apply it...
This **apply** action is what I'm missing, or that's what I think that I'm missing to make the modification remain even after deleting the boolean operand...

Comment: could you provide a sample file with the concerned meshes and the relevant part of the code?

Comment: the file is not directly accessible. could you make it public or use https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply`, the tile object is not the active object. Add the line commented below to you code.

Additionnaly, for the code as it is, as you have several tiles (I presume) but one modifier object, you should import this last one from outside of the loop (and remove it from outside of the loop too).

```
bool_mod = tile_obj.modifiers.new("Boolean", "BOOLEAN")
bool_mod.operation = 'DIFFERENCE'
bool_mod.object = modifier_obj
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = tile_obj           # <<<< add this
print(f"active object is {bpy.context.active_object.name}")
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=bool_mod.name)
```

Comment: Thanks @lemon, it works!
Before I was trying a similar solution (bpy.context.scene.objects.active = tile_obj) but I got an error.
I'll investigate what's the difference between .view_layer and .scene.

The reason why I open and close the modifier object inside the loop is because I want to export the modified tile once the modification is done. If I have the modifier object open at the time of saving the tile, it will appear in the exported model, which I don't want.
Is there a way of opening and closing the modifier object outside the loop and don't have it in the exported tile?

Comment: `bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl` has a parameter `use_selection=False` (False by defaut), if you `select_set(False)` the modifier obj and `use_selection=True`, that should do.